# Google Sheets: How do I get a player's name to move with sorting of numbers from another column?

Tags: google-sheets

Complete novice here so please bare with me.

Set up: Column B has the points each player has won. Column A has the players' names. I set Column B by so that each players' cumulative points are auto-sorted in descending order (creating a player's ranking). As players' points are added, Column B sorts automatically.

What I can't figure out is how to get the players' names to move with their associated points when the rank is updated. Right if B1 is auto-sorted to B4, the end results is A1-B4. I need it to be A4-B4.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: You said that B is sorted automatically. Do you use a script to achieve that ? If yes, edit your question and include that code.

Comment: I did say that but because I’m a total noob I just realized that when I right clicked and selected “sort” it only did it once instead of automatically *facepalm* I don’t have a script running which makes sense why what I’m doing isn’t working

Comment: if you want a formula solution then the answer that is already posted is correct. Otherwise let us know so we can prepare a script for you to actually do it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have column A with names and column B with points. (With headers in first row)

Then paste this `=sort(A2:B, 2, FALSE)` into D2.

The `A2:B` is selecting columns A and B.
The `2` is the column that is used for sorting.
And `FALSE` for descending order (`TRUE` for ascending)

You will get a new sorted list.

Example output:

```
Name | Points    Name | Points
Paul | 3         Peter| 10
John | 6         John | 6
Peter| 10        Paul | 3
```

Comment: Ya this is what I’m looking for I think! I’ll try it when it get back home :D thanks!

Comment: No problem, if it works for you mark this as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Apps Script [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger if you don't want to add more columns and sort A and B directly:

- Open the script editor by clicking **Tools > Script editor**.
- Copy this function and save the project:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2);
  const values = range.getValues();
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 2 && e.range.getRow() > 1) {
    values = values.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
    range.setValues(values);
  }
}
```

- Now, every time column B is edited, both A and B are sorted.

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)